# Retrieving the last insert id from MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySql database, one is `sales_order` and the other is `sales_order_details` which contains the details of the order in the `sales_order` table. Obviously, there is a one to many relationship from `sales_order` to `sales_order_details`.

When a customer places an order, the first entry is made into the `sales_order` table and based on the `auto_increment` id of the `sales_order` table, the corresponding entry is made into the `sales_order_details` table.

I'm using the `last_insert_id()` MySql function to retrieve the corresponding `order_id` from the `sales_order` table, Something like this.

```
insert into sales_order_details(order_id, prod_id, prod_price)values(last_insert_id(), 5, 1500);
```

It's working. The `last_insert_id()` function retrieves the last inserted id from the respective table which is unique to a particular connection (as far as I know).

Now, I need the same `order_id` which is retrieved and inserted most recently by the `last_insert_id()` function to send it as an invoice number to a payment system.

I can try using the PHP function `mysql_insert_id()` but I'm not sure whether it works as specified. What is the correct way to retrieve the last insert id which always guarantees to retrieve the specific id which is always associated with  a particular order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **2 ways** which you could solve this:

After inserting the entry in the sales_order:

1. Get the `last_insert_id` and store it in a php variable, then inject this value into the relevant queries.
2. Store the `last_insert_id` in a MySql [user-defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) and use the variable in the query instead of `last_insert_id`.

#### sample code for option 2

`SET @last_order_id = last_insert_id();`

```
insert into sales_order_details (order_id, prod_id, prod_price)
values (@last_order_id, 5, 1500);`

insert into sales_invoice (order_id, invoice_id)
values (@last_order_id, 1);`
```

Comment: `last_insert_id` returns only 1 id, you call it once after you insert the order and save it. Then you use this saved value where you need it.

Comment: So use `SELECT last_insert_id();` to get only the last id

Answer (score 1):

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

is the property you are looking for. It is completely reliable.

mysql_insert_id (and all mysql_ functions) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Both *LAST_INSERT_ID()* and *mysql_insert_id()* work as advertised i.e.: they will retrieve the last id inserted into any table during the current session/connection.

As long as you do not insert into more than one auto incremented table before retrieving this id, you're sure it's the correct one.

Also be careful when inserting multiple values into the same table, you'll receive the value for the first one of them but they are not necessarily consecutive (a different session/connection could have inserted some new records too).

I usually like to do things like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO sales_order ...;
    SET @last_order = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO sales_order_details (order_id) VALUES ($last_order);
    SELECT @last_order;
COMMIT;
```

The result-set of this query should contain a single column and a single row holding the value of the last order.

But then again I usually do that for transactional safety of updates most of all.

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT * FROM sales_order WHERE order_id = 2 FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE sales_order_details SET quantity = 9 WHERE order_id = 2 AND prod_id = 3;
    UPDATE sales_order SET price_to_pay = (SELECT SUM(quantity*price) FROM sales_order_details WHERE order_id = 2);
COMMIT;
```

The transaction should ensure the operations are atomic (all done without interruption by other processes);

If you were to do the same without a transaction or from the application code, the quantity might be updated by another thread and read by a third thread before you were done updating the price. Yielding a false "price_to_pay" to the user.

Comment: Yes, they are session/connection specific and PHP is entirely synchronous. If you were working with an event-driven language or a language which could support asynchronous functions, or threading, you might get into trouble because your events/async-functions/threads are sharing the same connection, otherwise it's reliable.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_insert_id( )` always returns the id generated for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` collumn by the **previous** query. (See the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php))

I don't understand exactly which id you want to fetch, but in order to retrieve it using PHP you should always do so directly after the query. For example:

```
// Query A

mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO table_a ( id, name ) VALUES ( NULL, "Henry" )' );
$idA = mysql_insert_id( );

// Query B

mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO table_b ( id, name, a_id ) VALUES ( NULL, "Wotton", ' . $idA . ' )' );
$idB = mysql_insert_id( );

// Query C
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO table_c ( id, name, a_id ) VALUES ( NULL, "Rick", ' . $idA . ' )' );
```

The advantage of storing them in a PHP variable is that your system or framework can't mess up your queries by performing another query while you are not aware of it.

Comment: @Tiny I think (but I'm not sure about that) that the `last_insert_id` only exists in the current connection, and that your system or other people accessing your website at the same time don't affect it. But still I wouldn't rely on a temporary, easily overridable value in your database when performing multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to restructure you queries just a bit.

1. Insert the record into the `sales_order` table
2. Use the php function `mysql_insert_id()` to retreive the id of the `sales_order` record: `$sales_order_id = mysql_insert_id()`
3. Rewrite your insert like so: `insert into sales_order_details(order_id, prod_id, prod_price)values($sales_order_id, 5, 1500);

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mysql_insert_id()` right after insering sales_order. You'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Database

    CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )


-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1.   Example (MySQLi Object-oriented)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>

------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   2.  Example (MySQLi Procedural)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>

------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  3.  Example (PDO)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDBPDO";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
        VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

    $conn = null;
    ?>
```